# How to loop records table row by row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below are my tables :

Table:

```
ID   Name   category
--------------------
1    test   1
2    test   2
3    test1  3
4    test1  4
```

Category:

```
ID  Name    
------------
1  simple   
2  complex
3  ordinory
4  ex-ordinory
```

In my table have 'Name' column. Each name has a category.

I need to fetch all names with categories wise.

```
select * 
from table
inner join category ca on ca.id = table.category
where name = test 
  and category = 1
```

This query will return only `name = test` with `category = 1` records

But I need to fetch all the names with their categories.

I am thinking to loop all the records row by row. Please suggest possible way to do this operation.

Comment: Remove where clause

Comment: In any relational database - **do NOT** think "row-by-agonizing-row" - this is the *worst possible* approach. Think in **sets** - you need to define what you need and let the database handle the details of how to get this for you - do **NOT** loop, this is madness !

Comment: @Sravanti did my answer help you? If so please mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

**CODE**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (ID INT IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(25), CATEGORY INT)
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
VALUES ('test',1),('test',2),('test1',3),('test1',4)

CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (ID INT IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO CATEGORY
VALUES ('Simple'),('Complex'),('Ordinary'),('Ex-Ordinary')

SELECT DISTINCT 
         T.NAME
        ,C.NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME T
JOIN CATEGORY C
ON C.ID = T.CATEGORY
```

**RESULT**

```
TABLE_NAME  CATEGORY_NAME
test           Complex
test           Simple
test1        Ex-Ordinary
test1         Ordinary
```

Comment: My thing i have to call SP for each row of result table.....i will pass name (ex:name)and category(complex) to the SP...it will give final results...so each row results i have to append and to display final results at last row of output.

Comment: @Sravanti what is in the SP? Is there any reason why you cant consolidate whats in the SP with this?  You don't want to do what you're asking. Performance will be terrible. With that said, you could use a Cursor to accomplish this.